# Trouble in using H2 database while creating it for Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

Facing below error while using h2 database in Spring boot application. (Could not find any proper solution for this). Please help me out to resolve this

**Error :**

Class "org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver" not found [90086-214]
org.h2.message.DbException: Class "org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver" not found [90086-214]
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:212)
at org.h2.util.JdbcUtils.loadUserClass(JdbcUtils.java:200)
at org.h2.util.JdbcUtils.getConnection(JdbcUtils.java:297)
at org.h2.server.web.WebServer.getConnection(WebServer.java:808)
at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.test(WebApp.java:972)
at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.process(WebApp.java:241)
at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.processRequest(WebApp.java:176)
at org.h2.server.web.WebServlet.doGet(WebServlet.java:129)
at org.h2.server.web.WebServlet.doPost(WebServlet.java:166)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)

Comment: Can you show your h2 configuration or application.properties ?

Comment: Have you put the right driver version for org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc. ? The right dependency in your pom.xml ? And updated your Maven dependencies's project ?

Comment: @QuentinGenet Below are the application properties I have added : 

**spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db1**

Comment: This is an exception from H2 Console web servlet, its login window has Driver Class field and there are pre-configured saved settings for different database systems. A wrong predefined settings for Apache Derby were selected.

Comment: Hi `@QuentinGenet` , Yes now it is working .Thank you so much for your help. But I want to add one more point that: I had to change the Driver class in h2-console manually to `org.h2.Driver`. Previously it was `org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver` by default after running the application

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add a propertie for driver or change it ? Try to add something like this in your application.properties : `spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver`
`spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect.`